# does import module(or package).function actually import the whole module / package?

Tags: python

Say I want to

```
import module.function
```

does it actually imported the whole `module` into memory instead of just the `function`?

I want to ask this question because I thought only importing the function I need from a module reduces memory consumption.

**Edit**
Clarify my question and ask it in the following two contexts:
 1. `import module.function1` where `module` is a single `module.py` file which contains `function1` and other functions definition and classes definition etc.  Is the whole `module` loaded into memory or just the `function1` definition part?
 2. `import package.function1` where `package` is a package like `numpy` where it contains file hierarchy, like [Mike Tung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6772373/mike-tung) described below.  Is the whole package loaded into memory, or just the module file that contains the `function1` definition, or just the part of that module file which defines `function1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following structure

```
app/
├── foo/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo1.py
│   └── foo2.py
├── bar/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar1.py
└── app.py
```

When you say in app.py

```
import foo
```

you are saying import all the py files under foo for use in app.py

when you say:

```
import foo.foo1
```

you are saying I only want the contents of foo1.py

When you say:

```
from foo.foo2 import *
```

you are saying take all the stuff in foo2 and dump it in to the same namespace as app.py.

In scenario 1 you would have to qualify all your calls extremely specifically.

`foo.foo1.function()`

In scenario 2

`foo1.function()`

In scenario 3

`function()`

Ideally you would be using scenario 2 as it is a nice middle ground and helps to prevent namespace pollution.

Comment: so `import foo1.function()` doesn't cause `foo2.py` or `bar1.py` imported?

Comment: you can't even do that... you have to say `import foo.foo1` which would import only foo1 but not the others.

Comment: can I do `from foo.foo1 import function()`?

Comment: Yes you can that would pull foo1.function() in to your app.py namespace so you can call it as function()

Comment: when I do `from numpy import array` for example, I was told the whole `numpy` will be loaded.  Doesn't `numpy` have similar file structure as you shown, so shouldn't **only** the module containing `array` be loaded?  Unless core classes and functions in `numpy` are all in one single .py file, which I doubt.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does import the whole function.  The purpose of including the function is mostly for code style purposes.  It makes it easier to understand that you are only using that specific function in the module.

Whether you use

```
import module
```

or

```
import module.function 
# this is equivalent to "import module" since you will still have to type 
# "module.function()" to use the function.  See next answer for correct syntax
```

or

```
from module import function
```

has little impact on memory/performance.

Answer (score 2):

`import module.function` is an error, actually. You can only import submodules, not functions, with that syntax.

`from module import function` is not an error. `from module import function` would execute the entire module, since the function may depend in arbitrarily complex ways on the other functions in the module or arbitrary setup executed by the module.

Comment: so when `from numpy import array`, is the whole `numpy` module imported or only a submodule?

Comment: I ask this question trying to see how to reduce memory footprint when I import functions from packages like `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: @graffaner: `array` is not a submodule. As for when you actually do import a submodule, such as `from numpy import random`, it would load everything `import numpy` loads and also load the `random` submodule. (NumPy happens to load most of its submodules by default, including `random`, so this would actually load exactly the same things `import numpy` loads.)

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function/187471) indicates that the entire module is still imported even if you are only using a small part of it.